# Select the record with the greatest value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am stuck with a query where one table has many records of the same id and the columns have different values like this:

```
ID  Name Location  Daysdue  date
001 MINE NBI       120      13-FEB-2013
001 TEST MSA       111      14-FEB-2013
002 MINE NBI       13       13-FEB-2013
002 MINE MSA       104      15-FEB-2013
```

I want to return the one record with the highest days due, so I have written a query:

```
select id,max(daysdue),name,location,date group by id,name,location,date;
```

This query is not returning one record but several for each id because I have grouped with every column bearing that the columns are different. What is the best way to select the row with the largest value of Days due based on id irrespective of the other values in the other columns??

For example I want to return this as:

```
001 MINE NBI       120      13-FEB-2013
002 MINE MSA       104      15-FEB-2013
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you want something like

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               rank() over (partition by id
                                order by daysDue desc) rnk
          FROM table_name t)
 WHERE rnk = 1
```

Depending on how you want to handle ties (two rows with the same `id` and the same `daysDue`), you may want the `dense_rank` or `row_number` function rather than `rank`.

Comment: If I have two records having the same number of daysOverdue, then this query is returning Both records

Comment: @Stanley how to decide which record to return then?

Comment: @Stanley - Correct.  And that's why I asked about how you want to handle ties.  You could pick one row arbitrarily by using the `row_number` function rather than `rank`.  You could add additional criteria to the `order by` in the `rank` to ensure that you can choose a particular row.

Comment: I just need to return one row as I want to count the Number of rows. The query can return any of the ties rows.

Comment: @Stanley - If you want to arbitrarily pick one row, use `row_number` in place of `rank`.  If you're just going to count the rows, though, you'd really just want to do a `select count( dsitinct id ) from table_name`.

Comment: I need other fields apart from counting, but that `row_number` works just fine for my Problem. Thanks Man.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to find the `MAX(daysdue)` for each `ID`:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(daysdue) AS max_daysdue
FROM table
GROUP BY ID;
```

Then you can join your original table to this.

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM
    table t
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            ID,
            MAX(daysdue) AS max_daysdue
        FROM table
        GROUP BY ID
    ) m ON
        t.ID = m.ID
        AND t.daysdue = m.max_daysdue;
```

Note that you might have duplicate id's in case of a tie -- makes sense semantically I guess.

Comment: @Stanley I didn't assume it was unique. How does the result of this query differ from your expected result?

Comment: This still gives me duplicate records. I do not have any unique column :(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  id,daysdue,name,location,date 
FROM your_table 
  WHERE daysdue = (
    SELECT max(daysdue) FROM your_table
  );
```

Comment: I almost guessed that